# Amazon S3 : Unable to set Object Permission for EVERYONE to "View Permission"

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am a PHP Developer.
I am having trouble to set permission to object using PHP code.
I can give that permission using Amazon S3 interface as well, but that is not a solution for me, because I need to do that every time user upload any object.

Below is the image URL where you will find my problem. While uploading object I am unable to give only "View Permission".

http://awesomescreenshot.com/06e3s42y6e

Instead of "View Permission", "Open/Download" can be given by code.

Below is the code I am using.

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$response = $s3->create_mpu_object($bucket, $filename, array('fileUpload' => $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
                                    'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC,
                                    'contentType' => $FileType,
                                    'storage' => AmazonS3::STORAGE_STANDARD));
```

In above code for 'acl' parameter I can use below values:

AmazonS3::ACL_PRIVATE, AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC, AmazonS3::ACL_OPEN, AmazonS3::ACL_AUTH_READ, AmazonS3::ACL_OWNER_READ, AmazonS3::ACL_OWNER_FULL_CONTROL

But I am unable to give only "View Permission" to Object.

Comment: did you got answer ?